# Error opening vim

Tags: vim, go, vi, vim-plugin

I just installed VimPlug and several golang imported tools and plugins.  I'm not sure where the first place to look at in order to disable this installation of oracle since it's been replaced with guru.

```
$ vim
Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle
Error installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle: 
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: use only `fatih/vim-go` instead, it integrates guru, and once you have the basic plugin you can just run `:GoInstallBinaries`

Comment: @Plato add this as answer then. That is a best practise here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vim-Go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) - all in one Go plugin for Vim. The best plugin I ever saw. Thanks to [Fatih Arslan](https://github.com/fatih) (btw he made a lot of excellent tools for Go).